# add legend to graph according to node colors using Rcy3

Tags: graph, legend, cytoscape

I'm an advanced R user, but have just started recently using Rcy3 to create better visualisations of my graphs.. problem is I don't know how to add a legend to my figure that would explain the coloring of my nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the app "LegendCreator".  It's sort of in the beta stage, but it can be useful particularly for gradient legends.  It also supports automation, although generally, you'll want to manually position the legend.

-- scooter